# Is it possible to open links in notepad++ with single click?

Tags: notepad++, links

I think the default setting in notepad++ is to require double clicking on html links. I have found indication on the internet ( https://sourceforge.net/p/notepad-plus/discussion/331753/thread/cd670d36/#b776 ) that it may be possible to change this behavior such that it will only require a single link. I have not however been able to find the setting to allow this to occur. If this is possible, i would be grateful if someone could advise - thanks!!